# Filter table by all match dropdown without interrupt each other

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, angular2-pipe

i made two dropdowns with color and width (parameters for filtering) and table that bind data according to choosed parameters, but dropdowns not working together, they interrupt each other: like once it filter by color, then by width, but not by color and width
I write it on angular2 here is the code of my pipe:
(i dont know how to make it in write way)

```
 export class FilterDropDownPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
            return items.filter(
                (item) => {
                    console.log(item)
                    console.log(args)
                    // return item.platform === args && item.type === args;
                    for (let p in item) {
                        if (item[p] === args) {
                            return item[p] === args;
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```